# Shipping Request not working, reporting missing parameters

Tags: shipping, xml

While creating a shipping label I got this error

`Error #151 : Consignee segment Company Name Mandatory Required error`

I crosschecked the request XML and the Company Name is empty, however the customer has a company name.

The company name contains an `&` (ampersand) maybe this is problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Premise**
I suspect this bug could involve other shipping method as it is related to how the XML request is built at to an annoying behavior of `SimpleXMLElement::addChild`.
Basically if the string you are trying to insert in the XML contains a `&` addChild misbehave and insert an empty value for that node.

For this particular scenario the issue is here `Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Dhl_International::_doRequest()`.

```
$companyName = ($rawRequest->getRecipientContactCompanyName())
            ? $rawRequest->getRecipientContactCompanyName()
            : $rawRequest->getRecipientContactPersonName();

        $nodeConsignee->addChild('CompanyName', substr($companyName, 0, 35));
```

Because the company name is present and you have `&` the XML produced contains and empty field for that node

**REFERENCE:**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552957/rationale-behind-simplexmlelements-handling-of-text-values-in-addchild-and-adda